# How to replace the text in a replacement function macro with the column name (e.g. column "AY")

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Sorry for the confusing title,
I am new to VBA and macros, and I couldn`t find any replacement threads that could help me out.

My workbook holds daily forecasts in columns, and a separate column tracks the  difference between the current day vs previous day forecasts.

My current macro was recorded using the relative reference to insert a new column and copy over the current day forecast over to the new column.

I wish to create another macro that would then replace the formula in the difference column( e.g. BB10-**AY**10), to the new column (BB10-**AZ**10), however in the macro that was recorded, these texts strings seem to be hard values.

VBA:

```
Sub Test()
     ' Test Macro '
     ' ActiveCell.Offset(-8, -4).Range("A1").Select Selection.Copy ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select 
     Application.CutCopyMode = False 
     Selection.Copy ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.Select 
     Selection.Replace What:="AY", Replacement:="AZ", LookAt:=xlPart, _ SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _ 
     ReplaceFormat:=False ActiveCell.Offset(10, -4).Range("A1").Select 
     Application.CutCopyMode = False 
 End Sub
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to get this resolved?

-PN

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the strings in the cell and use the replace function such as:

```
For Each Cell In Selection
    Cell.Value = Replace(Cell.Value, "AY", "AZ")
Next Cell
```

***** Update *****

Set the rngSrc to a cell in the column you want

```
Sub ReplaceText()
    Dim rngSrc As Range: Set rngSrc = Range("AZ1")
    Dim Adr As String: Adr = Right(rngSrc.Address, Len(rngSrc.Address) - 1)
    Dim ColLetter As String: ColLetter = Left(Adr, InStr(Adr, "$") - 1)
    For Each Cell In Selection
        Cell.Formula = Replace(Cell.Formula, "AY", ColLetter)
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I wish to replace the hard values or text (AZ), with the whatever the new column would be. So lets say I create a new column the next day, I need to switch the text, "AZ" to "BB" within the formula in the "Current Day vs. Prev. Day" column.
I am trying to implement this into a bigger macro so that the user just presses a button to setup the new day.